# Spring Boot Security Bad Credentials even though credentials are correct

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I have a spring boot app with a custom user and a MySQL database, i make a post request to the user controller to add a new user with the username and password the user gets put into the database with the password encrypted just fine. But when i enter the credentials into the login form the login form returns Bad Credentials.

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig
{
    
    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService(DataSource dataSource)
    {
        return new JdbcUserDetailsManager(dataSource);
    }
    @Bean
    SecurityFilterChain defaultSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception
    {
        http.authorizeHttpRequests()
//                .requestMatchers("/**").permitAll()
                .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/api/users").permitAll()
                .and().formLogin().permitAll()
                .and().logout().permitAll()
                .and().cors().and().csrf().disable()
                .httpBasic();
        
        
        return http.build();
    }
    
    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder()
    {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
}
```

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/users")
public class UserController
{
    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;
    
    @Autowired
    private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;
    
    
 @PostMapping()
    public User insertUser(@RequestBody User user)
    {
        if (user.getId() != 0)
        {
            return null;
        }
        
        user.setPassword(passwordEncoder.encode(user.getPassword()));
        return userRepository.save(user);
    }
}
```

also user class for reference :

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User
{
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    
    @NotEmpty
    @Column(name = "username",nullable = false,unique = true)
    private String username;
    
    @NotEmpty
    @Column(name = "password",nullable = false)
    private String password;
    
    private boolean enabled = true;
    
    @Column(name = "email")
    @Email(message = "Email should be valid")
    private String email;
    
    @Column(name = "address")
    private String address;
    
    @Column(name = "AFM")
    private Long AFM;
    
    @Column(name = "phone_number")
    private Long phone_number;

    public User()
    {
    
    }
    
    public User(String name, String email, String address, Long AFM, Long phone_number)
    {
        this.username = name;
        this.email    = email;
        this.address = address;
        this.AFM = AFM;
        this.phone_number = phone_number;

    }
    

   //Getters Setters
```

I do a post request on /api/users with body of :

```json
{
    "username":"nikos gourn",
    "email":"nikos@gmail.com",
    "address":"kapio allo meros",
    "afm":98776,
    "phone_number":2109017131,
    "password":"123"
}
```

and the user is inserted into the database
[image]

now if i go to `http://localhost:7979/login`
and type in `nikos gourn` as the username and `123` as the password it gives me bad credential.

[image]

Am i doing something wrong, and who can i debug this process?

Comment: still bad credentials

Comment: i tried it with a user without any whitespaces , same problem , also the spring security debug just show the request headers , not a username sent or password, so how can it be if use?

Comment: Have you tried removing password encoding and checking if the originally encoded password version actually equals the encoded password you entered in the UI?

Comment: In your above set up there are no authorities defined for the user, spring security treats a user with no authority as not found.. see the snippet from spring security class JdbcDaoImpl -     

addCustomAuthorities(user.getUsername(), dbAuths);
  if (dbAuths.size() == 0) {
   this.logger.debug("User '" + username + "' has no authorities and will be treated as 'not found'");
   throw new UsernameNotFoundException(this.messages.getMessage("JdbcDaoImpl.noAuthority",new Object[] { username }, "User {0} has no GrantedAuthority"));
  }

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem by making a custom userdetails

```java
public class CustomUserDetails implements UserDetails
{
    private User user;
    
    public CustomUserDetails(User user)
    {
        this.user = user;
    }
    
    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities()
    {
        return null;
    }
    
    @Override
    public String getPassword()
    {
        return user.getPassword();
    }
    
    @Override
    public String getUsername()
    {
        return user.getUsername();
    }
    
    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired()
    {
        return true;
    }
    
    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked()
    {
        return true;
    }
    
    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired()
    {
        return true;
    }
    
    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled()
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

and a userdetailservice

```java
@Service
public class UserDetailsService implements org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService
{
    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;
    
    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException
    {
        User user =  userRepository.findByUsername(username);
        if (user == null)
        {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("Could not find user");
        }
        
        return new CustomUserDetails(user);
    }
}
```

and adding it to the securityfilterchain with `.and().userDetailsService(CustomUserDetailService)`